# WSL: make fails when using -j

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working on a project for my cryptography course, and I've been using the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Up until recently I was able to use `make -j` to build my entire project quickly.

Recently, I started getting compilation errors like the one below. Strangely enough, I have no issues compiling with just `make` (no `-j`)

Because this used to work fine, I do not believe the issue has anything to do with dependencies specified in my makefiles. (Most of my code is in header files anyway because templates)

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/cstdlib:72,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:5249,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52,
                 from tests/cryptomath/../../catch.hpp:207,
                 from tests/cryptomath/test_extgcd.cpp:2:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:219:25: fatal error: /home/ipiano/[student id]/Documents/Code/Homework/512/project/modules/module_crypto/unittests/../libclassiccrypto/affine/headers/sys/select.h: Invalid argument
```

It looks to me like the compiler is trying to find c++ source files (sys/select.h in this specific error) in my project directory, which implies maybe a path issue?

The only thing that I can think of that changed recently is that IT approved the Creator's Update and I installed that, but I don't know if it's relevant or not.

If anyone has seen this behavior or errors like this and knows how to resolve it, help would be appreciated.

---------EDIT---------

Was able to narrow down to a specific makefile that my main makefile was including. It was defining part of it's targets, but not all of them. Still not sure why the `-j` flag brought this to light, but at least it's working now

Comment: Well, if you show us the full compile command line when this error happens, and also a minimal makefile that shows the problem, maybe we can see something; with only the information you've provided here there's nothing we can say.  I can't imagine any issue that would both cause this compile error _and_ only happen with parallel builds.  Are you generating header files or source files during your build?  Or is everything straightforward C++ code, compiled and linked normally?

Comment: I have not done a minimal test... probably should have done that first; not in the habit. I'll put together a minimal test makefile and report back. There are no headers or sources generated during the build, to my knowledge.

Comment: So.... I was trying to make a minimal example, and, as one would expect, I was unable to. I went back to my original makefile and started editing out chunks until I could successfully make -j again. Then I started adding in bits and pieces until... the whole thing was there?

Does make have some sort of memory or cache to it that could have gotten messed up?

Comment: Well, your update _defining part of it's [sic] targets, but not all of them_ is suspicious but not detailed enough to comment on.  The single most common cause of problems when starting to use `-j` is missing prerequisite statements, which makes total sense: if you don't tell make that A depends on B, it might try to build both in parallel.  Note that make itself is not multithreaded, so there's no concern about memory or caching inside make due to `-j`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: my compilation failed when using "make -j*N*", for *N*>1. After some research I found the same issue described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2606).

The problem is likely caused by a bug introduced in DrvFs, the Windows filesystem plugin for WSL, and it happens at least in Windows builds 16273.1000, 16299.19 and 16299.64 (mine). It doesn't happen in build 16251.

According to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2448#issuecomment-342254181), the bug was fixed on Windows Build 16299.98.

Since I cannot update my Windows due the company policies and I couldn't execute this [workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2448#issuecomment-342254181), I moved my files from `/mnt/c` to `/home/<username>` and they compiled without further problems.